# call php function that generates xml file on a link

Tags: php, xml

a few hours since I ask a question to generate an xml with a php function, so i resolved it, but have now more problems, i can generate a single xml with calling a single function on the same document, but when i call more than one i have problems, that's my code:

```
function getPVPxml($codi){
$query="SELECT preu FROM producte where codi = $codi";
$result=mysql_query($query);
header("Content-type: text/xml");

$xml="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>".chr(13).chr(10);
$xml.="<producte>".chr(13).chr(10);
$xml.="    <codi>".$codi."</codi>".chr(13).chr(10);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $xml.="<preu>".$row['preu']."</preu>".chr(13).chr(10);

$xml.="</producte>".chr(13).chr(10);


header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8559-1");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='ws_getPVPxml.xml'");
return $xml;
}
```

So, i see a post on this page with a possible way to do this, i implemented that:

```
if(isset($_GET['getPVPxml'])){
    $xml=getPVPxml(1);
}

echo "<a href='servidor.php?getPVPxml='".$getPVPxml."''>getPVP</a>";
echo '<a href="servidor.php?getPVPxml='.$getPVPxml.'">getPVP</a>';
```

these two echos are tests with diferent position of the single ' and the ", but returns error too.

I'm doing wrong something, but don't know where it is the mistake, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing function calls and variables

This is  variable

```
$getPVPxml;
```

This is a function call

```
getPVPxml($codi);
```

This assigns the result of a function to a variable

```
$pvpXML = getPVPxml($codi);
```

Comment: so, jake it should means that i gonna change $getPVPxml to $xml?